# No data received - Passenger, (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I had setup Elastic Beanstalk for my rails application last month (Passenger).
All was good.. but all of a sudden, my servers are not responding well.

My application access gives 'No data received - Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data." on the browser.

When I curl the application, I get curl: (52) Empty reply from server.

Is it passenger issue ? I am a newbie to administering server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache or Nginx?

If Apache, take a look at your logs (probably in /var/log/httpd/, especially error_log).

Update your post with that info and people will be more likely to know what your problem wow.